# Jenkins shows as "Failed to connect to repository" on enter of repository URL

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Here is error message shown

```
Failed to connect to a repository: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/org/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Login failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/org/project.git/'
```

Attaching screenshot for the error shown:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUGY4.png)

I went through multiple platforms about the configuration issue but none of them seems to be in sync with the same. Some of them talk about git executable path that seems to be correct but don't know what actually is validated here to say git repository not found. Even after providing valid credentials as well it shows the same error.

It started showing this error message after running for 100 builds don't know what went wrong after those builds trying to configure from scratch shows the above error message. However in another machine with the same setup able to run jobs. Can someone let me know if there are any chances of the issue being with the machine as well?

Job log:-

```
Started by user Tom
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Create
using credential "xyz"
git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
git.exe config remote.origin.url giturl # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from giturl
git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials xyz git
git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress giturl +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from giturl
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:894)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1148)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1179)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress giturl +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
    stdout: 
    stderr: remote: Not Found
    fatal: repository 'giturl/' not found
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:892)
    ... 11 more
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: So, you definitely have a problem with credentials. Have you tried to provide right credentials in `Credentials` parameter, then save job and then try to execute? If so, could you provide us with the error logs of your job?

Comment: @biruk1230 added the job log to the description. Credentials are the right ones that are working in machine 'x' same credentials are not working in 'Y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue in the below steps

1. Run this on the command line

   ```
   git.exe ls-remote URL
   ```
2. Then provide the git credentials
3. After successfully doing the above steps, you will find all the heads of the repository as shown in this screenshot:

   [image]
4. Now go to Jenkins, provide your git repository URL in SCM, and then add the credentials of your Git repo in the credentials.

Then, the above issue "Failed to connect to the repository” will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

From the log I see that you're trying to reach fake `giturl` instead of actual address of the repository.:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress giturl +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
...                                                           ####^HERE^####
...
fatal: repository 'giturl/' not found
```

So, you need to specify the actual URL of your Git repository instead of `giturl` (something like `git@github.com:Company/Repo.git`).

Comment: I provided the actual URL of git but I modified the git URL when provided the logs to you since I don't want me to let to know my company's repository.

Comment: It won't work in such way :)
Please execute with real git URL and provide us with error log (but change the URL to a fake one after the execution).

Comment: Or maybe I didn't understand you correctly and you have the actual error log. If so, then you still need to check the URL of your actual repository, because you have these errors: 
`stderr: remote: Not Found
    fatal: repository 'giturl/' not found`

Comment: Have you tried to check the connection to your repository from your host when it's not working?
Also I recommend to clean your workspace before the build and to re-install Git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, what worked for me was simply changing the clone URL from SSH to HTTPS

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31234414)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by copying the URL of the Git repository (the same one you would use for a "git clone " command)

[image: screenshot]